# CSS full height div with margin?

Tags: css, html

I've looked everywhere, and can't figure out if there's a way to do this. Basically, I want to mimic this layout, without using the CSS3 attributes:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
 <title>Bad way...</title>
 <style>
  html,body{
   margin:0px;
   height:100%;
  }
  .tall{
   background-color:yellow;
   min-height:100%;
   height:100%;
   padding-top:50px;

   -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
   box-sizing:border-box;
  }
  .short{
   background-color:blue;
   height:100%;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class='tall'>
 <div class='short'>
  Foo bar baz
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't care how much extra markup or CSS there is, as long as its cross-browser compatible. I would just settle with the ol' faux columns, but it won't work in this situation. The `short` div is going to have an iframe, which needs to be the full height.

The `tall` div is just there to show what its supposed to look like. All I want, is a div that is full height, but with a 50px margin on top. All of my attempts just extend the height to 100% + 50px.

I know I can do it with JavaScript, but I would really like to get a CSS solution if its possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-remaining-screen-space

Comment: Hmmm, none of those answers seem to work if a `height:100%` iframe is used as the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use absolute positioning as described here: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/conflictingabsolutepositions/

You can specify all sides of div e.g.

```
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
right: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

Comment: You might be able to achieve this with box-sizing css3 property as well

Answer (score 1):

Instead of " padding-top:50px;" in .tall{} use margin-top:50px;

Comment: My example just shows what kind of a div I want: I want a div that acts the same way as `short`, without using CSS3. Basically, a `max-height:100%` div with a `margin-top:50px`.

Answer (score 1):

remove:

```
.tall{
   min-height:100%;
  }
```

along with css3 property. Should work fine. New css would look like

```
.tall{
   background-color:yellow;
   height:100%;
   padding-top:50px;
  }
  .short{
   background-color:blue;
   height:100%;
  }
```

Comment: That makes the `tall` div extend beyond the page to height 100% + 50px. I need 100% to be the max-height for the page.